# proliferating asterisks in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I am writing an ebook with MS Word 2007, using Styles, and want to separate sections with 3 asterisks, but every time I type the 3 asterisks (using Centering Style) it proliferates into a row of asterisks. Not what I want. Appreciate any suggestions. 
A poster in another area suggested I put blank spaces around the asterisks, but I'm not sure how to do that. Is there a way to turn off whatever feature is creating a line of asterisks?

Answer (score 2):

[corrected]
Turn off auto-format for that option:

Click the round button in the top left corner;  choose the Word Options button at the bottom of the menu that opens.

Go to Proofing > AutoCorrect (at top) > click AutoCorrect Options.

On the "Autoformat as you Type" tab, in the middle under "Apply as you type", uncheck the "Border Lines" box.

[image: Autcorrect options explained]

Word is actually creating a paragraph border;  to remove the border that you didn't want:
in Word 2007, on the Home tab, in the Paragraph group. The bottom right button is the Borders button; click the arrow beside it and select No Border.